# Check if one element in array is being used, if so, use another element

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, switch-statement

How do I check if one element is being used, and if so to use another element on the Switch Case statements.

```js
//Input
function myFunction() {
  
var myArray = ["60","50", "20", "30", "15", "10"];
  var randomJumpingJacks = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomCrunches = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
   
    var workOut = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  
  
var text = "";
for(const char of workOut.toUpperCase()){
    switch(char) {
        case "A":
        case "I":
        case "N":
        case "X":
            text += randomJumpingJacks;
            text += " Jumping Jacks";
                  
        break;
        case "B":
        case "J":
        case "Q":
        case "Y":
            text += randomCrunches;
            text += " Crunches";       
          break;
          case " ":
            /*text += " break ";*/
        break;
       
        default:
        text += "I have never heard of that fruit...";    
    }
  text +=" "
  text +="<br>"
}
  
    document.getElementById("excercise").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Input some characters  and click the button.</p>
<p>Your excericse routine will display based on your input.</p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p>
  <span id="reps"></span>
  <span id="excercise"></span>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Example:
I typed: ABBY 
I'm expecting it to output:

10 Jumping Jacks

15 Crunches

10 Crunches

20 Crunches

I'm unsure if I'm using the correct terminology, but I'm going to refer cases A,I,N,X as Jumping Block, and cases B,J,Q,Y as Crunches Block.

If the chars called are from the same block, there's a tendency to display the same random number.

On the second Char (B) of the Crunches block, it naturally outputs 15, but since it is being used for the first char (also B), I'd like it to use some other element,

and the third char (Y) being on the Crunches block as well, I'd like it to use a different element that are different from the first two elements, and so forth, and repeat after 4 times.

I'd love to know what you think.

Comment: So you are going to have to change your logic to keep track of the numbers that are used for each exercise. Many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the random logic inside of the for loop. To get a new random number for each letter in the string, you need to reassign the value each time the loop goes through. See the code below.

```js
function myFunction() {
  
var myArray = ["60","50", "20", "30", "15", "10"];

   
    var workOut = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  
  
var text = "";
for(const char of workOut.toUpperCase()){
  var randomJumpingJacks = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomCrunches = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

    switch(char) {
        case "A":
        case "I":
        case "N":
        case "X":
            text += randomJumpingJacks;
            text += " Jumping Jacks";
                  
        break;
        case "B":
        case "J":
        case "Q":
        case "Y":
            text += randomCrunches;
            text += " Crunches";       
          break;
          case " ":
            /*text += " break ";*/
        break;
       
        default:
        text += "I have never heard of that fruit...";    
    }
  text +=" "
  text +="<br>"
}
  
    document.getElementById("excercise").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Input some characters  and click the button.</p>
<p>Your excericse routine will display based on your input.</p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p>
  <span id="reps"></span>
  <span id="excercise"></span>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly, but to be honest, i don't understand the logic, could you explain it to me?

Comment: Sure @Ebizl, when you assign the variable before the loop it will always have the same variable in the loop. But getting the random number at the beginning of each loop will change its value with each pass of the loop.

Comment: It baffles me that putting it in the for block can cause such difference. Thank you very much

Comment: @Ebizl think os it like this. The code inside the for block get ran each time it loops. So if the loop were to run 5 times, all the code in the for block would run from start to finish 5 times. The code outside the for block only gets ran one.